# event.pageY position always coming as per laptop screen size and not as per scrolled clicked position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a scrollable page. Its `event.pageY` position is always coming as per my screen size, I mean even if I scroll down a lot and click near the screen top, it comes to be like `50px`.

I am using

```
event.pageY
```

On a normal html page this works perfectly fine but in my Angular page, the data loads dynamically and in this case it is behaving weird as per the laptop screen position and not the page scroll position.

Comment: Consider looking at `scrollY`? The `pageY` value is how far away the element is from the top of the page, not the screen.

Comment: [ts] Property 'scrollY' does not exist on type 'JQueryEventObject'.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't spot the jquery tag. Maybe https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/ will help?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, event.pageY returns the Y axis' value relative to the screen. You have to add total scrolled amount to it.
So it would be as following:

```
event.pageY + document.body.scrollTop
```

Comment: I tried but in angular2 it was giving error using scrollTop, I'll recheck and get back

Comment: not giving error but it is also showing same answer `console.log(event.pageY+ document.body.scrollTop);` and `console.log(event.pageY);` showing same result

Comment: the value of `document.body.scrollTop` is always coming out to be 0.